# Import file with global with ES6 import

Tags: javascript, webpack, three.js, webpack-2

Im trying to import files from threejs library, which was moved to modules, but some of functionalities (like the `VRControls`) inside examples folder are using the global namespace `THREE`.

I've tried different approaches with the webpack `imports-loader` like:

```
import "imports-loader?THREE=three!../node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/VRControls.js";
```

`console.log(VRControls)` or `console.log(THREE.VRControls)` produces errors.

other attempt was to write the loader inside the babel config

```
return {
    target: 'web',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/application.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www'),
        filename: debug ? 'bundle.js' : 'bundle.min.js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    plugins,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
                ],
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    compact: true,
                    presets: [
                        ['es2015', {modules: false}]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.\.[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]three[\/\\]examples[\/\\]js[\/\\].*[\/\\].*\.js/,
                loader: "imports-loader?THREE=three"
            }
        ]
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    }
};
```

and inside the app importing the file

```
import "../node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/VRControls.js";
```

gave also errors.
How can such cases be imported without the necessity to pull the whole library?

Comment: can you share error?

Comment: `VRControls.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined`